# Ray[tune] for pytorch TypeError: ray.cloudpickle.dumps

Tags: python, pytorch, ray, ray-tune

I am having trouble getting started with tune from Ray. I have a PyTorch model to be trained and I am trying to fine-tune using this library. I am very new to Raytune so please bear with me and help me understand where the error stems from.

my training function:

```
# Training and Validation
def train(resnet18, start_epoch=0, end_epoch=500, checkpoint_dir=None, optimizer=None, train_dataloader=None, val_dataloader=None):
    n_epochs = 500
    epoch = 0
    since = time.time()
    train_loss_history = []
    val_loss_history = []
    best_acc = 0
    # Load checkpoint
    if checkpoint:
        checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_dir)
        resnet18.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
        optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
        epoch = checkpoint['epoch'] + 1
        best_acc = checkpoint['best_val_acc']
        optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] = 0.001
    
    for epoch in range(start_epoch, end_epoch):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{n_epochs-1}')
        running_loss, running_corrects = 0.0, 0.0
        resnet18.train()
        for inputs, labels in train_dataloader:
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = resnet18(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataset)
        train_loss_history.append(epoch_loss)
        epoch_acc = running_corrects.float() / len(train_dataset)
        sw.add_scalar("train/loss", epoch_loss, epoch)
        sw.add_scalar("train/Acc", epoch_acc, epoch)


        resnet18.eval()
        running_loss, running_corrects = 0.0, 0.0
        for inputs, labels in val_dataloader:
            outputs = resnet18(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)

            running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

        epoch_val_loss = running_loss / len(val_dataset)
        val_loss_history.append(epoch_val_loss)
        epoch_val_acc = running_corrects.float() / len(val_dataset)
        sw.add_scalar("val/loss", epoch_val_loss, epoch)
        sw.add_scalar("val/Acc", epoch_val_acc, epoch)


        if epoch_val_acc > best_acc:
            best_acc = epoch_val_acc
            torch.save(resnet18.state_dict(), "best_res18_1.pt")
        
        torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': resnet18.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'train_loss': epoch_loss,
            'val_loss': epoch_val_loss,
            'best_val_acc': best_acc
        }, "checkpoint_res18.pt")

    #     sw.add_scalar("learning_rate", lr_update.get_last_lr()[0], epoch)
    #     lr_update.step()
        print(f'train loss: {epoch_loss}  train Acc: {epoch_acc}   val loss: {epoch_val_loss}  val Acc: {epoch_val_acc}')
        print('-'*10)

    
    print(f'training time: {time.time() - since}')
    return best_acc
```

and here I train try tuning:

```
def training_function(config):
    sgd = optim.SGD(resnet18.parameters(), lr=config['lr'], momentum=config['mom'], nesterov=config['nest'])
    train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False, sampler=weightedSampler)
    val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
    resnet18 = models.resnet18(pretrained=False).to(device)
    resnet18.fc = nn.Linear(512, 29).to(device)
    for i in range(10):
        best_acc = train(resnet18=resnet18, optimizer=sgd, train_dataloader=train_dataloader, val_dataloader=val_dataloader)
        tune.report(mean_accuracy=best_acc)

config = {'lr': tune.grid_search([0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001]), 
          'mom': tune.grid_search([0.98, 0.9, 0.8]),
          'nest': tune.choice([True, False])}

analysis = tune.run(training_function, config)
```

and the error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e74d4c4e9dfc> in <module>
     13           'nest': tune.choice([True, False])}
     14 
---> 15 analysis = tune.run(training_function, config)

~/anaconda3/envs/py37-start/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py in run(run_or_experiment, name, metric, mode, stop, time_budget_s, config, resources_per_trial, num_samples, local_dir, search_alg, scheduler, keep_checkpoints_num, checkpoint_score_attr, checkpoint_freq, checkpoint_at_end, verbose, progress_reporter, log_to_file, trial_name_creator, trial_dirname_creator, sync_config, export_formats, max_failures, fail_fast, restore, server_port, resume, queue_trials, reuse_actors, trial_executor, raise_on_failed_trial, callbacks, loggers, ray_auto_init, run_errored_only, global_checkpoint_period, with_server, upload_dir, sync_to_cloud, sync_to_driver, sync_on_checkpoint, _remote)
    415                 export_formats=export_formats,
    416                 max_failures=max_failures,
--> 417                 restore=restore)
    418     else:
    419         logger.debug("Ignoring some parameters passed into tune.run.")

~/anaconda3/envs/py37-start/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/experiment.py in __init__(self, name, run, stop, time_budget_s, config, resources_per_trial, num_samples, local_dir, upload_dir, trial_name_creator, trial_dirname_creator, loggers, log_to_file, sync_to_driver, sync_to_cloud, checkpoint_freq, checkpoint_at_end, sync_on_checkpoint, keep_checkpoints_num, checkpoint_score_attr, export_formats, max_failures, restore)
    150                     "checkpointable function. You can specify checkpoints "
    151                     "within your trainable function.")
--> 152         self._run_identifier = Experiment.register_if_needed(run)
    153         self.name = name or self._run_identifier
    154 

~/anaconda3/envs/py37-start/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/experiment.py in register_if_needed(cls, run_object)
    303                              "\n-If the error is typing-related, try removing "
    304                              "the type annotations and try again.")
--> 305                 raise type(e)(str(e) + " " + extra_msg) from None
    306             return name
    307         else:

TypeError: ray.cloudpickle.dumps(<class 'ray.tune.function_runner.wrap_function.<locals>.ImplicitFunc'>) failed.
To check which non-serializable variables are captured in scope, re-run the ray script with 'RAY_PICKLE_VERBOSE_DEBUG=1'. Other options: 
-Try reproducing the issue by calling `pickle.dumps(trainable)`. 
-If the error is typing-related, try removing the type annotations and try again.
```

My guess is I am missing something obvious, I could not find this error on SO or github.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code. Didn't run into any serialization issue. Here is the result (error only because I didn't include every pytorch dependencies)

```
| Trial name                    | status   | loc   |     lr |   mom | nest   |
|-------------------------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+--------|
| training_function_dc6c3_00000 | ERROR    |       | 0.01   |  0.98 | False  |
| training_function_dc6c3_00001 | ERROR    |       | 0.001  |  0.98 | True   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00002 | ERROR    |       | 0.0001 |  0.98 | False  |
| training_function_dc6c3_00003 | ERROR    |       | 1e-05  |  0.98 | True   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00004 | ERROR    |       | 0.01   |  0.9  | False  |
| training_function_dc6c3_00005 | ERROR    |       | 0.001  |  0.9  | True   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00006 | ERROR    |       | 0.0001 |  0.9  | True   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00007 | ERROR    |       | 1e-05  |  0.9  | True   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00008 | ERROR    |       | 0.01   |  0.8  | False  |
| training_function_dc6c3_00009 | ERROR    |       | 0.001  |  0.8  | False  |
| training_function_dc6c3_00010 | ERROR    |       | 0.0001 |  0.8  | True   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00011 | ERROR    |       | 1e-05  |  0.8  | False  |
+-------------------------------+----------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
Number of errored trials: 12
+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Trial name                    |   # failures | error file                                                                                                                                                   |
|-------------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| training_function_dc6c3_00000 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00000_0_lr=0.01,mom=0.98,nest=False_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00001 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00001_1_lr=0.001,mom=0.98,nest=True_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00002 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00002_2_lr=0.0001,mom=0.98,nest=False_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt |
| training_function_dc6c3_00003 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00003_3_lr=1e-05,mom=0.98,nest=True_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00004 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00004_4_lr=0.01,mom=0.9,nest=False_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt    |
| training_function_dc6c3_00005 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00005_5_lr=0.001,mom=0.9,nest=True_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt    |
| training_function_dc6c3_00006 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00006_6_lr=0.0001,mom=0.9,nest=True_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00007 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00007_7_lr=1e-05,mom=0.9,nest=True_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt    |
| training_function_dc6c3_00008 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00008_8_lr=0.01,mom=0.8,nest=False_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt    |
| training_function_dc6c3_00009 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00009_9_lr=0.001,mom=0.8,nest=False_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt   |
| training_function_dc6c3_00010 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00010_10_lr=0.0001,mom=0.8,nest=True_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt  |
| training_function_dc6c3_00011 |            1 | /Users/xwjiang/ray_results/training_function_2021-09-11_07-52-18/training_function_dc6c3_00011_11_lr=1e-05,mom=0.8,nest=False_2021-09-11_07-52-19/error.txt  |
```

btw, when you call `tune.run`, do it like `tune.run(train_func, config=config)`; otherwise, the config you passed in is mistaken as `name`.